# Dual NIC not working

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04 with two on-board NICs. Ubuntu sees both cards, but both eth0 and eth1 will only pass traffic out of one physical interface, although they are configured separately (I think). Information is below:

```
lshw -C network
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 54:be:f7:65:9a:9b
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=172.22.1.112 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:26 memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff memory:f7e39000-f7e39fff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 00
       serial: 54:be:f7:65:9a:9c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=2.1-3 ip=172.22.1.113 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7d00000-f7d1ffff ioport:e000(size=32) memory:f7d20000-f7d23fff
```

`/etc/network/interfaces:`

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# The secondary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Thank you for any help!

`ifconfig:`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:be:f7:65:9a:9b
          inet addr:172.22.1.112  Bcast:172.22.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::56be:f7ff:fe65:9a9b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5880 (5.8 KB)  TX bytes:1436 (1.4 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:be:f7:65:9a:9c
          inet addr:172.22.1.113  Bcast:172.22.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::56be:f7ff:fe65:9a9c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:575 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:88205 (88.2 KB)  TX bytes:42753 (42.7 KB)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)
```

`route -n:`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.22.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
172.22.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
172.22.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

route -n with eth0 unplugged. Cannot access either ip address.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.22.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.22.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
172.22.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

```
Script with eth0 disconnected

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:be:f7:65:9a:9b
          inet addr:172.22.1.112  Bcast:172.22.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::56be:f7ff:fe65:9a9b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28527 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2202058 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:1372 (1.3 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:be:f7:65:9a:9c
          inet addr:172.22.1.113  Bcast:172.22.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::56be:f7ff:fe65:9a9c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:31516 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1730 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6125004 (6.1 MB)  TX bytes:155950 (155.9 KB)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.22.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
172.22.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
172.22.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=27.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=25.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=27.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=26.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=58 time=26.6 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 25.818/26.897/27.860/0.733 ms


Script with eth1 disconnected

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:be:f7:65:9a:9b
          inet addr:172.22.1.112  Bcast:172.22.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::56be:f7ff:fe65:9a9b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28540 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2202968 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:1372 (1.3 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:be:f7:65:9a:9c
          inet addr:172.22.1.113  Bcast:172.22.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::56be:f7ff:fe65:9a9c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:31528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6125988 (6.1 MB)  TX bytes:156460 (156.4 KB)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.22.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
172.22.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
172.22.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4031ms
```

Comment: Will you add the output of `ifconfig` to your question?

Comment: eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:be:f7:65:9a:9b
          inet addr:172.22.1.112  Bcast:172.22.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::56be:f7ff:fe65:9a9b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5880 (5.8 KB)  TX bytes:1436 (1.4 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000

Comment: eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:be:f7:65:9a:9c
          inet addr:172.22.1.113  Bcast:172.22.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::56be:f7ff:fe65:9a9c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:575 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:88205 (88.2 KB)  TX bytes:42753 (42.7 KB)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000

Comment: lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)

Comment: I can't make out the content you are showing.  If you paste it [to your questions here](http://askubuntu.com/posts/894079/edit) I'll be able to see it better.

Comment: Added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Both your NICs are working.  One of them have they have the individual IP addresses of:

```
eth0: 172.22.1.112
    and
etho1: 172.22.1.113
```

You can verify that both of them are working by pinging either IP address:

```
$ ping -c10 172.22.1.112
$ ping -c10 172.22.1.113
```

If you have another computer in your network you can also access your computer from either IP address.

If you set up a web server on your machine, you would be able to access the web server by using either of the IP addresses:

```
http://172.22.1.112
http://172.22.1.113
```

The access (output you see with either of those examples is verification that they both are working.  Also, the fact that your `dhcp` server was able to access them and assign IP addresses is another verification that they **both** are working.

**Run this script to test the NIC's separate:**

Copy and paste the script below.  You can name it: `testnic.sh`.
Run the script individually while each nic is plugged into the computer and the router/modem.

`testnic.sh:`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ifconfig
route -n
sudo route del default gw 172.22.1.1
sudo route add default gw 172.22.1.1
ping -c5 8.8.8.8
```

Run the command as:

```
$ ./testnic.sh
```

Show both the command and the output.

**Update:**

Your previous output shows indicates the problem as mentioned is in the route.  You have to delete the previous root when you remove that nic, then create another route in it's place.

Below is an example script to help you with that task.  The script will have to be tested and fine tuned for your environment.  But the answer to your question is specific, that **both nics are working.  The difference you are seeing is the result of how you have them configured.**

When removing one NIC, change your network configuration to use the routing of the one remining.

**This is another script example to make it easy to change configurations when you switch the NICs.**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

currentroute=$(route -n | awk '/UG/{print $NF}')
available="none"

route="0"
available="none"
find /sys/class/net/en* -exec echo "{}/operstate" \; | while read line; do
    # echo "[$line]"    
    IFS='/' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
    device="${array[4]}"
    state="$(cat $line)"
    thisdevice="$device:$state"
    if [[ "$thisdevice" == "$currentroute:down" ]] ; then
        route="0"
    fi
    if [[ "$state" == "up" ]]
    then
        echo "The device $device is available"
        echo "$device" > /tmp/available             
    fi 
done
read -r available </tmp/available
if [[ "$route" == "0" ]]; then
    route del default gw 172.22.1.1 $currentdevice
    route add default gw 172.22.1.1 $available
fi

echo "[$route/$available]"
```

Comment: I can ping both, but if I unplug one of the cables I lose both interfaces. If I unplug the other, I don't lose any. I can still ping both.

Comment: Will you add the output of `route -n` to your question?

Comment: @ L.D. James Added

Comment: Your gateway is on `eth1`.  It is `172.22.1.1`.  When you remove that NIC you are removing your gateway.  You'll have to assign a gateway to the `eth0` device after removing the `eth1` device.  You can add a new default gateway with this commaind: `sudo route add default gw 172.22.1.1`

Comment: Stepped out for a meeting. I'll try that when I'm done. Thanks!

Comment: I get the following message when trying to add the route.

Comment: SIOCADDRT: File exists

Comment: I want traffic to pass through both physical nics with different ip addresses. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Before adding the new default route, delete the previous one.  This will resolve the `IOCADDRT: File exists` error message.  Delete the previous one with: `sudo route del default gw 172.22.1.1` Then add the new one, just change the `del` argument to the `add` argument. `sudo route add default gw 172.22.1.1`.  You can do it in a one liner: `sudo route del default gw 172.22.1.1 && sudo route add default gw 172.22.1.1`

Comment: Didn't work. With eth1 removed and running that command still cannot ping either address.

Comment: Will you show the output of `route -n` when it's not working?  Append the output to your question to make it easier to read.

Comment: I would love to but with the cable unplugged I cannot access it from this computer, so I will list it the best I can. I did notice that eth0 and eth1 switched as the default gw.

Comment: 0.0.0.0  172.22.1.1  0.0.0.0  UG  0  0  0  eth0 ===
172.22.1.0  0.0.0.0  255.255.255.0  U  0  0  0  eth0 ===
172.22.1.0  0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0  U  0  0  0  eth1

Comment: I can't make out the output.  Would you mind appending it to your question?  You can save the output to a test file.  Then when you reconnect to the internet, append it to your question.  The exact output would be helpful.  It helps me in reproducing the problem on my work bench test machine and makes it easier for me to see the difference.

Comment: Just posted the results.

Comment: Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Give me a minute to create a script for you to run.  I'll  append it to my answer.

Comment: A `testnic.sh` script is added to the answer.  Add the text output to your question.

Comment: Ran script and added info to the question

Comment: I see the problem.  The script didn't totally delete the previous gateway.  So the gateway didn't change as intended when running it the second time.  I'll modify the script and it should work.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @AnthonyRivera I updated the answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56323/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-dual-nic-not-working).

Comment: @AnthonyRivera  Were you ever able to solve your problem?  I have have the exact same query and I'd like to know if you were successful.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a bond interface to bundle both cards into one virtual interface?

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
        mtu 9000

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
        mtu 9000

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
    mtu 9000
    bond-mode 0
    bond-primary eth0
    bond-slaves eth0 eth1
```